# Como cambiar un valor según se active o desactive un checkbox en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy haciendo un panel de precios y necesito cambiar el valor del total según se active o desactive un checkbox con forma de botón on/off.
Realmente no estoy usando la función del checkbox, pues no se porque razones misteriosas de la programación no me funcionaba, así que pensé en activar y desactivar el checkbox con cada click, contar los clicks y según el numero de clicks fuera par o impar actuar de una manera u otra, pero no hay manera. Estoy bastante atascado, así que agradecería cualquier ayuda, aunque sea otra perspectiva diferente. La llamada de jQuery de prop() no me funcionaba, solo me funcionaba si le daba el valor true, pero eso activaba directamente el checkbox y no es lo que busco.
Pongo el código al que hace referencia la cuestión, si necesitan algo más, pídanlo. Gracias por su ayuda, espero haberme explicado.

El checkbox

```
 <label class="switch">
 <input id='checktotal-sim' type="checkbox"/>
 <span class="slider round"></span>
 </label><button class='btonmas'>Más info</button></p>
```

Javascript

```
var valorchecksim = 1;     //No cambiar valor
    
    const checksim = 2;   
    const checkfijo = 6;  

  
   $('#checktotal-sim').click(function(){
        
        simtotal = document.getElementById('total').textContent;
      

        if (valorchecksim %2 !==0){            
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(simtotal) + checksim;       
            document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML = parseInt(simtotal) + checksim; 
            
        }if (valorchecksim %2 ==0) {
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(simtotal) - checksim;      
            document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML = parseInt(simtotal) - checksim;       
        }
       
        valorchecksim++;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues es tan simple como seleccionar el elemento y preguntas si está marcado usando `.is(':checked')`. Dentro del if haces lo que quieras hacer en cada caso.

```js
$('#checktotal-sim').click(function(){
    if($('#checktotal-sim').is(':checked')){
      // Acá dentro pones tu código para cuando esté seleccionado
      $('.slider.round').html('¡Hola! Me has seleccionado')
     } else {
     // Acá dentro pones tu código para cuando NO esté seleccionado
      $('.slider.round').html('¡Que lástima! Te arrepentiste')
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <label class="switch">
 <input id='checktotal-sim' type="checkbox"/>
 <span class="slider round"></span>
 </label><button class='btonmas'>Más info</button></p>
```